# Sufficient conditions for $x, Ax, A^2x, ...$ being linearly indepedent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. What is a sufficient condition for $$x, Ax, A^2x, ..., A^{n-1}x$$ being linearly independent?

Comment: Is this really a duplicate of the marked question?  That one gives a sufficient condition, but seems to only apply to the case that $A$ is nilpotent of index $n$.  I think there is room for an answer that is more general than that one.

Answer (score 3):

A possible sufficient condition is that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is irreducible and $x\ne0$. Unfortunately, with base field $\Bbb R$, we cannot have irreducibility if $n>2$.

Answer (score 3):

By the Popov-Belovich-Hautus (PBH) test in control theory, $x,\,Ax,\,\cdots,\,A^{n-1}x$ are linearly independent *if and only if* the augmented matrix $[A-\lambda I|x]$ has rank $n$ for every complex eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$.

Comment: Is the augmented matrix n by n+1? Is $x $ appended to $A - \lambda I$?

Answer (score 3):

If the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has no repeated roots, then we have a basis $\{v_i\mid 1\leq i \leq n\}$ of eigenvectors for $\mathbb C^n$, and we can express $x=\sum \alpha_i v_i$ in terms of the basis.  If all of the $\alpha_i$ are non-zero, then all of your vectors will be linearly independent.  In fact, with this condition on $A$, this is a necessary and sufficient condition on $x$.

Here is a quick proof.  Let $\lambda_i$ be the eigenvalues, $v_i$ the eigenvectors, and $f(x)$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$.  Let $g_i(x)=f(x)/(x-\lambda_i)=\prod_{j\neq i} (x-\lambda_j)$, and let $h_i(x)=g_i(x)/g_i(\lambda_i)$.  Then one can check that $h_i(A)v_j=\delta_{ij}v_j$.  If $x=\sum a_i v_i$, then $h_j(A)(x)=a_j v_j$, so each eigenvector is a linear combination of $x, Ax, A^2x, \ldots$.  Since the eigenvectors are linearly independent, this shows  that $\dim \operatorname{Span}(x,Ax,\ldots A^{n-1}x)=n$.  On the other hand, if we could write $x$ as a linear combination of some subset of the eigenvectors, then $A^kx$ would also be a linear combination of that same subset, so  $\dim \operatorname{Span}(x,Ax,\ldots A^{n-1}x)<n$.

If $A$ has an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity greater than $1$, then no $x$ will work. Indeed, $\dim \operatorname{Span}(x,Ax,A^2x,\ldots)\leq \dim \operatorname{Span}(I,A,A^2,\ldots)$ which is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$.  So a necessary condition is that the minimal polynomial equals the characteristic polynomial, which prevents $A$ from having geometric multiplicity greater than $1$ for any eigenvalue.

If $A$ has repeated eigenvalues but all eigenvalues have geometric multiplicity of $1$, then it is still possible to find such an $x$, but things are a bit more complicated.  If $A$ is in JNF, then each block has a generator, and if we express $x$ with respect to the basis for the JNF, we need the coefficients of all the block generators to be non-zero.  Explaining this is a bit involved, though.

Comment: In the first case, $v_i, \alpha_i$ and eigenvalues are all complex. But we are talking $x$ and $A$ with real entries.

Comment: @Harvett but if there are complex eigenvslues and eigenvectors, you can take complex coefficients to get real results. In particular, complex eigenvectors come in complex conjugate pairs, and if you give them complex conjugate coefficients, you will get real results.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, I can still not see why this would lead to $x,Ax,A^{2}x,\dots,A^{n-1}x$ *all* being lineraly independent. Where do you prove this satement?

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer Consider the span of $A^kx$ for all $k$.  If $P(x)$ is a polynomial, then $P(A)x$ is in the span.  Now, suppose that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $f(x)$, which has no repeated roots.  If $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue, then let $g_i(x)=f(x)/(x-\lambda_i)$.  Then $g_i(v_j)=0$ if $i\neq j$, $g_i(v_i)=g_i(\lambda_i)v_i\neq 0$ otherwise.  So $g_i(A)/g_i(\lambda_i)$ is projection onto the $i$th eigenvector (with respect to the eigenbasis).  Using this, we see that if $\sum a_i v_i$ with $a_i\neq 0 \forall i$, then $v_i$ is in that span.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Aaron. I cant really decide what kind of mathematical object the $g_{i}$ are. They are polynomials constructed from the characteristic polynomial $f(x)$ by dividing by one of the roots' factors. However, then you insert an eigenvector $v_{i}$ into it, how am I to interpret this? Or is $x$ also a vector? That you can insert a matrix into the polynomial that I understand what it means. I am just confused about how we can insert a vector.

Comment: That was a typo. I meant $g_i(A)x$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $K$ is the base field with the algebraic closure $\bar{K}$.  Let $f(t)\in K[t]$ denote the minimal polynomial of $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(K)$.  First, the situation is trivial if $f(t)$ is of degree less than $n$.  We now assume that $f(t)$ is of degree $n$.

Suppose that $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_l\in\bar{K}$ be the distinct eigenvalues of $A$ with algebraic multiplicities $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_l$, respectively.  Denote by $I$ the $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix.  For $i=1,2,\ldots,l$, fix $$a_i\in\ker\big((A-\lambda_i\,I)^{m_i}\big)\setminus \ker\big((A-\lambda_i\,I)^{m_i-1}\big).$$  Extend $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_l\}$ to a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\bar{K}^n$ consisting of generalized eigenvectors of $A$ .   Write $V_i$ for the $\bar{K}$-span of $\mathcal{B}\setminus\{a_i\}$ for every $i=1,2,\ldots,l$.

Suppose that $x\in K^n$ is such that $x$, $Ax$, $A^2x$, $\ldots$, $A^{n-1}x$ are linearly independent over $K$.

There exists a monic polynomial $p(t)\in K[t]$ of degree at most $n-1$ such that $p(A)\,x=0$.  This shows that $q(t):=\gcd\big(p(t),f(t)\big)$ also satisfies $q(A)\,x=0$. This implies that $x$ lies in the kernel of $q(A)$.  Because $q(t)$ is of degree at most $n-1$, it follows that there exists $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,l\}$ such that $(t-\lambda_i)\,q(t)$ divides $f(t)$. Consequently, $x\in V_i$ for some $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,l\}$.

Conversely, assume that $x\in K^n$ is such that $x\in V_i$ for some $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,l\}$.  Then, $p(A)\,x=0$, where $p(t) \in K[t]$ is the monic polynomial such that $p(t)\,q(t)=f(t)$, where $q(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\lambda_i$ in $K[t]$.  Thus, $p(t)$ has degree at most $n-1$, and so $x$, $Ax$, $A^2x$, $\ldots$, $A^{n-1}x$ are linearly dependent.

In conclusion, we have proven the following.  For a fixed $x\in K^n$ and $A\in \text{Mat}_{n\times n}(K)$, $x$, $Ax$, $Ax^2$, $\ldots$, $Ax^{n-1}$ are linearly independent if and only if

- the minimal polynomial of $A$ equals its characteristic polynomial,
- $x\notin V_i\cap K^n$ for any $i=1,2,\ldots,l$, where the subspaces $V_i\subseteq \bar{K}^n$ are defined as above.

However, I am not sure how useful this formulation will be.